# What is the recommended site for asking about system trading?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Currently, I'm looking into [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/home.php), which, as far as I understood, is a platform for online trading.  Some aspects of making use of this site can be stated as a "programming problem", which makes it suitable for Stack Overflow.

Some other aspects, however, does not necessarily fit into a programming site.  One question I want to solve for now is:

> **Billing.** Under what circumstance will I be billed? Will subscribing to contents in a test account (called paper account) bill me or not? What kind of service activation is best suited for getting started on just the development?

Since this is not necessarily a programming question, I wanted to ask if there is any site suitable for this kind of question to be asked.

Comment: Maybe at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such questions are usually a better fit for the company's own support site. Interactive Brokers has a fairly extensive [knowledge base](https://ibkr.info/) and [API documentation](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/). From personal experience (I'm co-founder of a financial advisor; our clients have IB accounts and we submit orders via the IB API), I know that they're rather quick and good in reacting on support tickets. They have a lot more knowledge about their own products than a random bunch of strangers on a network of Q&A sites.

The Stack Exchange site which covers the subject of investing/trading is [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com). Their [help center](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions that the following questions are on-topic:

> - Use of software for managing one's finances. (Not recommendations, just questions regarding specific software)
> - Securities trading and investing, whether long- or short-term, as practiced by retail traders and investors. (Excludes specific security recommendations, stock tips/discussion, forecasts.)
> - Investing and trading strategies, including fundamental and technical analysis and other techniques, as practiced by retail traders and investors. (again excluding specific recommendations and evaluation of conditions)

"What kind of service activation is best suited for getting started on just the development?" sounds like a recommendation and is definitely off-topic, the other parts might work. E.g. you have to pay for live data for stock prices, but you can usually get *delayed* data (from 15 minutes ago) for free. This is probably an interesting fact for future visitors as well.